# Selenium can not find any element using css, xpath, name, id (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, authentication, automation

I want to log into a forum, already bypassed the cookie message by switching to its iframe but I can't get access to anything on the page. This is my code:

```
#set path, open firefox
path = r'C:\Users\Anwender\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)

#open bym forum
driver.get('https://www.bym.de/forum/')
driver.maximize_window()

#deal with cookie
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP   Consent Message']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[title='Zustimmen']"))).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

So far, so good. Now a ton of ads pop up. I try to get to the login:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('navbar_username')
username.send_keys("name")
password = driver.find_element_by_id('navbar_password')
password.send_keys("pw")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/form/fieldset/div/div/input[4]").click()
```

I have tried different variants of this using the css selector or the xpath. Didn't work. Then I tried waiting 20 seconds till everything has loaded. Didn't work. I tried accessing a different element (to a subforum). Didn't work.
I tried:

```
try:
    wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "navbar_username"))
                )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Selenium just can not find this element, the browser just closed. I have looked for iframes but I couldn't find any in the html. Is it possible I am not even on the main "window"? "Frame"? "Site"? I don't know what to call it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched to an iframe and closed it, but you never switched back! Selenium is still on the closed and absent iframe. Switch back to the mainpage using:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```